# App works in >apk 17, but crashes in apk 11 device custom action bar not working

Tags: android-actionbar, custom-titlebar

This code works fine in the handset devices with android level 4.0.. but crashes with android 3.0....

The code in bold is where the error log points to... the screen shot of error log is given

public class Main extends Activity
{
    ImageView villas, apartments,plots,gaButton;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    <b>setContentView(R.layout.main);</b>
    //getActionBar().hide();
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);

    villas=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.villas);
    apartments=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.apartments);
    plots=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.plots);

        }
    });


    initializeActionBar();
}
```